# How to update a Jtable?

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I created a java swing application, which takes data from a database, and displays it in a JTable. I'm currently just trying to view all the data in my database. But when I click the button to send the query to the database and view the obtained data on the jtable, the table does not update. This is my code:

`TableData.java`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class TableData extends JPanel {
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private final Object Column[] = {"id", "titolo", "autore", "prezzo"};
    TableData(){
        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        table = new JTable(model);
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(Column);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public void updateTable(Object row[]){
        model.addRow(row);
    }
}
```

`ConnectionDB.java`

```
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class ConnectionDB {
    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:4444/database_name";
    private String user = "root";
    private String password = "password";
    TableData tableData = new TableData();
    //id titolo autore prezzo
    public void upload_data(String titolo, String autore, int prezzo){
        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            String query = "insert into libri(titolo, autore, prezzo)" +
                           "values ('"+titolo+"','"+autore+"','"+prezzo+"')";
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println("success");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void get_data(){
        Object row[] = new Object[4];
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from libri");
            while(resultSet.next()){
                for(int i = 1; i<=4; i++){
                    row[i-1] = resultSet.getString(i);
                }
                tableData.updateTable(row);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`PanelForm.java`

```
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;

public class PanelForm extends JPanel {
    ....somebutton.....
    ConnectionDB conn = new ConnectionDB();

    ....some board....
        buttonVisualizza.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                conn.get_data();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my `HomePage.java`

```
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import java.awt.*;

public class HomePage extends JFrame {
    private PanelForm panelForm;
    private TableData tableData;
    HomePage(){
        super("Home");
        setSize(800,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(200,200);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panelForm = new PanelForm();
        tableData = new TableData();
        add(panelForm, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(tableData, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

I have already tried to reload the model, and this command:  `model.fireTableDataChanged();`

Comment: You're not "updating" afaics. Where is the method `upload_data` called?

Comment: It's odd that TableData extends JFrame, shouldn't it be just a data-container? Are you sure that the connection is referencing the same JTable, that you have in your PanelForm?

Comment: the `upload_data` method is used to upload data in the database, I use the `get_data` method, to get data from database. @ValerijDobler I'm not sure about that, I think that is the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: yes, I have deleted some not relevant object and I uploaded the code about visible component

Comment: What you posted is incomplete. Nothing has added `TableData` to anything here so as far as we're concerned, you shouldn't see *anything*

Comment: You have two separate and unconnected instances of `TableData`. The one you display is *not* the one owned by the connection-bound class, so will do nothing

Comment: As @user85421 has requested, please create and post your [mre] with this question. You are asking about code that runs but that misbehaves, and the best way for us to figure out why is to have working code that reproduces the problem. This is not a request for the entire program but rather for a new small program. Please read or re-read the link. Comment if you have any questions about the construct.

Comment: @g00se how can I connect the two instances of TableData? Sorry, but I'm still a novice

Comment: You don't want to connect them. You need to get rid of one of them. I think your shortest route for now is to get rid of `ConnectionDB` but to incorporate its code into `TableData`. Make sure you only create *one* instance of that class. Every query should close all db objects

Comment: 1. You might want to investigate concepts like dependency injection and the observer pattern.  2. Your `ConnectionDB` should be generating a data model.  This would then be either be wrapped in or update a `TableModel` which would be attached to the `JTable` itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So immediately, you're creating multiple instances of `TableData`....

```
public class ConnectionDB {
    //...
    TableData tableData = new TableData();

public class HomePage extends JFrame {
    private PanelForm panelForm;
    private TableData tableData;
    HomePage(){
        //..
        tableData = new TableData();
```

Neither of these two instances have anything to do with each other, so updating one will not update the other.

This suggests that you need to spend some more time researching concepts like

- [Dependency injection](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+dependency+injection&oq=java+dependency+injection)
- [Single Responsibility Principle](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+single+responsibility+principle)
- [Model-View-Controller](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+model+view+controller)

Let's start with, you're using an Object Oriented language, this means, you should be trying to describe your data more as "objects" rather then a lose connection of elements in an array.

Let's start with a "book" concept...

```
public interface Book {
    public String getTitle();
    public String getAuthor();
    public int getPrice();
}
```

I like `interface`s they free your code from changes which might occur at an implementation level, should you need to shift your data source from say something like a local database to a web API.

Having said that, we're still going to need a concrete implement...

```
public class DefaultBook implements Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int price;

    public DefaultBook(String title, String author, int price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

I might be tempted to also inject that the records database key into an implementation, but that's details you can address later.

Next, lets take a look at the `ConnectionDB`...

```
public class ConnectionDB {
    //...
    public void upload_data(String titolo, String autore, int prezzo){
        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            String query = "insert into libri(titolo, autore, prezzo)" +
                           "values ('"+titolo+"','"+autore+"','"+prezzo+"')";
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println("success");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is not only inefficient and slow, it's also dangerous.

Create a new instance of the `Connection` each time is slow and you're leaving yourself open to [sql injection](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+sql+injection) attacks.  You're also not closing any of the resources, which could mean that the connection will keep them open, degrading the performance of your database.

Start by taking a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Instead, you should be making use of dependency injection to pass in a reference to the `Connection`.  This resolves the class of the responsibility of creating the connection, allow you to create what ever connection you need to what ever database you want.

```
public class ConnectionDB {
    private Connection connection;

    public ConnectionDB(Connection connction) {
        this.connection = connction;
    }

    protected Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public void uploadData(Book book) throws SQLException {
        try(PreparedStatement statement = getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into libri(titolo, autore, prezzo) values (?, ?, ?)")) {
            statement.setString(1, book.getTitle());
            statement.setString(2, book.getAuthor());
            statement.setInt(3, book.getPrice());
            statement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("success");
        }
    }

    public List<Book> getData() throws SQLException {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>(32);
        try (Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement()) {
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select titolo, autore, prezzo from libri");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String title = resultSet.getString(1);
                String author = resultSet.getString(2);
                int price = resultSet.getInt(3);
                
                books.add(new DefaultBook(title, author, price));
            }
        }
        return books;
    }
}
```

You will note that `getData` returns a `List` of `Book`s, this is important, as it removes any implementation details that previously existed.  The `ConnectionDB` doesn't care how you might use the data, only that when requested, it will return a `List` of data for you.

Also note, I'm not consuming the errors.  Error management (beyond cleaning up the resources) isn't this classes responsibility, the caller will want to know when something goes wrong.

Okay, let's move onto the UI by stating with how you would model the data from `ConnectionDB` for the UI.

I would, personally, create a custom `TableModel` which could take a `List` of `Book`s and model it as I needed, for example...

```
public class BookTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private List<Book> books;
    private String[] columnNames = new String[] {
        "Title", "Author", "Price"
    };

    public BookTableModel(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return getBooks().size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Book book = getBooks().get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return book.getTitle();
            case 1: return book.getAuthor();
            case 2: return book.getPrice();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return String.class;
            case 1: return String.class;
            case 2: return Integer.class;
        }
        return Object.class;
    }        
}
```

This is important, because I could use a `ListModel` instead if I wanted to!  Same data, different presentation!

```
public class BookTable extends JPanel {
    private JTable table;
    
    public BookTable(BookTableModel model) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        table = new JTable(model);
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    protected JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public BookTableModel getModel() {
        return (BookTableModel) getTable().getModel();
    }

    public void setModel(BookTableModel model) {
        getTable().setModel(model);
    }
}
```

Now, unless my UI was suitably complex, I might not seperate the table management to a seperate class, instead, I might just do something like...

```
public class BookPane extends JPanel {
    private ConnectionDB connectionDB;
    
    private JTable bookTable;

    public BookPane(ConnectionDB connectionDB) {
        this.connectionDB = connectionDB;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        // You could add a empty constructor to the
        // BookTableModel to make this a bit easier
        bookTable = new JTable(new BookTableModel(new ArrayList<>()));
        
        add(new JScrollPane(bookTable));
        
        JButton loadButton = new JButton("Load");
        loadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    List<Book> data = getConnectionDB().getData();
                    // You could just replace the `List` managed by
                    // BookTableModel, but this is just simpler
                    getBookTable().setModel(new BookTableModel(data));
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(BookPane.this, "Failed to load data", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ConnectionDB getConnectionDB() {
        return connectionDB;
    }

    protected JTable getBookTable() {
        return bookTable;
    }               
}
```

So, how does this all tie together?  Well, maybe something like...

```
Connection connection = ...; // Create an instance of a Connection for your database
ConnectionDB connectionDB = new ConnectionDB(connection);

EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new BookPane(connectionDB));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```